# Chrome Dev Tools > Selecting text right to left while debugging don't work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I searched the web and I didn't found a single person complaining about this issue but the truth is, while debugging I can't select a block of text from right to left and then add a Watch or put my mouse hover the selection to see it's value, for example. But if I select the same block of code left to right it works.

Can anyone tell me if it's a real bug or if there's a reason for this behavior?

I've tried in Windows, Mac Os and Ubuntu, every time with the same behavior...

Cumps.

Comment: Block of text from _right to left_? Which view in dev are you referring to?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer.

I'm referring to the sources panel...

Cump's